# Error when trying to load postgres 15 on ubuntu

Tags: linux, postgresql

Has somebody expirienced this error also in ubuntu 22.02, i am using docker ubuntu 22.02. But it seems postgres15 not avaible any more...

Thanks!

Build script:

```
RUN apt update && apt install wget gnupg gnupg2 gnupg1 -y
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(echo lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
RUN wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -
RUN apt update && apt-get install -y postgresql-15 postgresql-client-15
```

Error:

````
    #10 0.138 
    #10 0.138 WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
    #10 0.138 
    #10 0.237 Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
    #10 0.259 Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
    #10 0.282 Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
    #10 0.341 Ign:4 https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt lsb_release InRelease
    #10 0.380 Err:5 https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt lsb_release Release
    #10 0.380   404  Not Found [IP: ***.**.**.** 443]
    #10 0.424 Reading package lists...
    #10 0.684 E: The repository 'https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt lsb_release Release' does not have a Release file.
    ------
    executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt update && apt-get install -y postgresql-15 postgresql-client-15]: exit code: 100```
````

Comment: 1) The 1-3 hits indicate you are using Debian not Ubuntu. 2) Postgres 15 is definitely available from the Postgres repos.

Comment: sry my mistake i have multiple servers running ubuntu and in the container running debian and vice versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$(echo lsb_release -cs)` passed the string `lsb_release` into the sources.list.

Try instead:

```
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
```

If the installation still fails, try also in addition to install the package [postgresql-common](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/postgresql-common)